# How does one get Redmine to update its database to reflect the contents of the configured git repository

Tags: git, redmine

```
Redmine 3.4.11.stable
PostgreSQL-9.6
Git-2.24.1
```

I have a situation where the git repo configured in one of my projects is not having its most recent commits picked up by Redmine.  However the updated files themselves are viewable through the Redmine repository browser pages.  Stuff from last fall and earlier are all there.

I do not know how this happened but it has.  How do I get Redmine to re-read the git repository and reset itself?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it, one way, if you take like github repo for example would be to have a local copy on your server where Redmine resides, and like a cron job updating it every 5 minutes...

So first you have to clone the repo to your Redmine user's
folder like this for example:

```
git clone mygitproject /home/redmine/repos/mygitproject
```

and your Redmine user would have cron entry like:

```
*/5 * * * *  cd /home/redmine/repos/mygitproject && git fetch -q --all -p
```

Then in Redmine, on your project, the **settings -> repositories** tab
would have entry like this:

**/home/redmine/repos/mygitproject**

This way you would have 5min delay in your Redmine.

If you want to have change in real-time, then you would need post-receive hook on your git server to like login to your Redmine server via SSH and perform manual git update, and wget script to update reposities via Redmine repositories webservice and key that you can find in Redmine's admin settings, Repositories tab...

The entire shell code for post-receive hook could be like:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no redmine@yourserverip
match_max 100000
expect "*?assword:*"
send -- "Password#!\r"
expect "*?elcome*"
send -- "cd redpo\r"
send -- "git pull\r"
expect -re ".*dat"
wget "http://<redmine url>/sys/fetch_changesets?key=<your service key>"
```

You can also find official guides here:
https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_setup_automatic_refresh_of_repositories_in_Redmine_on_commit

Comment: Evidently, I did not make myself clear.  The Redmine installation is properly configured to point to the local bare repository at `/var/db/git/project.git`.  That repo IS the primary remote and all updates are pushed to there.  I recently pushed an update to that repo from my workstation.  The update is in the git repo.  Redmine shows the updated file in its view page.  But the actual commit is not shown.

Comment: What I am looking for is some sort of technique to have Redmine re-read the git repo and detect and add any commits that are in the repo and are not in Redmine's database.

Comment: Post-update hook in your local repo to trigger Redmine repository webservice (last line wget from my answer above). Btw, answer is good for common use-case scenario, people still use github a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to resolve this issue was to delete the repository reference in Redmine and then add it back.  This forced Redmine to first remove and then reconstruct its internal references.  The down side to this approach is that references to commits that are contained within issue notes or wiki pages are removed and are not reconstructed.